# VisualForce: Picklist multiple checkboxes

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im trying to display checkboxes that are multiple selectable. These checkboxes get their value from multi-picklist values from a custom object.

This works and Im able to save the values.

Is there any way to autogenerate checkboxes based on PickList values?

Comment: did any of these answers solve the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `apex:selectCheckboxes`:

In your controller have:

```
public list<string> checkboxSelections {get;set;}  //holds the values of the selected checkboxes

public list<selectOption> getMyCheckboxes(){
    //create list of checkboxes
    list<selectOption> myOptions = new list<selectOption>();
    for(integer i=0;i<5;i++)
        myOptions.add(new selectOption(string.valueof(i),string.valueof(i));  // selectOption = (value,label)
    return myOptions;
}
```

And in your Visualforce page:

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!checkboxSelections}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!MyCheckboxes}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

See the following documentation:

- [apex:selectCheckboxes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectCheckboxes.htm)
- [apex:selectOptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm)
- [SelectOption Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm)

---

To get a list that contains every picklist value of a field, see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-get-a-picklist-all-values-in-apex-controller):

Copied from the [other post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-get-a-picklist-all-values-in-apex-controller):

```
global static list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues(SObject obj, String fld){
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();
    // Get the object type of the SObject.
    Schema.sObjectType objType = obj.getSObjectType(); 
    // Describe the SObject using its object type.
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();       
    // Get a map of fields for the SObject
    map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap(); 
    // Get the list of picklist values for this field.
    list<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
    // Add these values to the selectoption list.
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values){ 
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 
    }
    return options;
}
```

Another version but simplifed for a VF controller and a little easier to work with (*note the difference in inputs*):

```
public list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues(string myObjectName, String myField){
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();

    sObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    if(objectType==null)
        return options; 

    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objectType.getDescribe();  

    Schema.SObjectField theField = objDescribe.fields.getMap().get(myField);

    if(theField==null)
        return options;

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a :theField.getDescribe().getPickListValues())
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 

    return options;
}
```

If you need to do this often, try making a "Utility" Apex class and add this method as a static method.  Write code once and forever.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to building it using purely VisualForce and Apex markup, if you are using the jQuery library (or can) you could use the [toChecklist plugin from Scott Horlbeck](http://www.scotthorlbeck.com/code/tochecklist/). The plugin takes a standard multi-select picklist and creates a nice list of checkboxes in its place.

The two specified options, `submitDataAsArray = false` and `preferIdOverName = false` are required for proper operation of the plugin in a VisualForce page. This plugin may also work for `<apex:inputField />` tags bound to multi-select picklist field types, but I have not tested using it in that context yet.

*Note:* As written in the 1.5.0 source, the syntax for ID selectors is not compatible with VisualForce IDs because of the colons being interpreted as pseudo-selectors. I have modified both the standard and minified JavaScript source files to use compatible ID selector syntax and placed the files in a Gist [which can be found here](https://gist.github.com/mpond76/6223566).

**VF Markup:**

```
<apex:selectList id="checkboxPicklist" value="{!selectedValues}" multiselect="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectOptions}" />
</apex:selectList>

<script>
    jQuery('[id="{!$Component.checkboxPicklist}"]').toChecklist({ submitDataAsArray: false, preferIdOverName: false });
</script>
```