# State and Country picklist Scanning in apex

Tags: picklist

I want to check if `state` exists or not with a `country` in State and Country Picklist feature supported by Salesforce. I want to do this in Apex. How can I do this?

Comment: As I presume its the dependencies that you are interested in, I think getting hold of that information is pretty awkward - see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, when the <kbd>State and Country Picklist feature</kbd> is activated, it overrides the `State` and `Country` fields you currently have in your <kbd>Standard Objects</kbd>.  Therefore, the State and Country fields should still be **picklists** but with the available values updated.

Hence, I believe you should be able to find `State` and `Country` picklist values like you would any other picklist:

See my answer here for code samples on **how to find picklist values in APEX**:  [VisualForce: Picklist multiple checkboxes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/visualforce-picklist-multiple-checkboxes/15402#15402)