# Extract time from time picklist

Tags: apex

I want to extract time from time picklist(12 PM,12 AM,4PM ,6:15 PM are picklist values) in apex like

- 12 PM as 12:00:00
- 12 AM as 00:00:00
- 4 PM  as 16:00:00
- 6:15 PM as 18:15:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Datetime.parse(String datetime)

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse

It works like

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

Now you have just a time and there is no such function on the Time object. As a workaround use a fake date and extract the time component with DateTime.time()

```
Time t = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM').time();
```

In your case

```
Time t = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 ' + YouObject__c.YourPicklist__c).time();
```

Comment: I have just time as picklist values not Date Time

Comment: If you have a field of type picklist, it's value is type string. DateTime will be output and not input type.

Comment: If you want to convert ALL possible pv, you need schema methods http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-get-a-picklist-all-values-in-apex-controller  and then the above

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

dev,

Here is a method you could use to convert those picklist values into a time string. You can tweak as you like if you actually want to get a Time out of it.

```
public string convertTime(string t)
{
    //Add the minutes if they are not provided
    if(!t.contains(':'))
    {
        t = t.replace(' ','');
        t = t.replace('PM',':00 PM').replace('AM',':00 AM');
    }

    //If AM or PM not included, add AM as default
    if(!t.contains('AM') && !t.contains('PM'))
    {
        t += ' AM';
    }

    //Turn the time into a DateTime
    string dtime = '01/01/15 '+t;
    //Parse it and extract the time
    string result = string.valueOf(DateTime.Parse(dtime).time()).replace('.000Z','');
    return result;
}
```

Good luck!

Luis