# Valid values for ContentType

Tags: apex, knowledge, contenttype

I am creating a KAV article using Apex code. One of fields is a file field, and I set the various fields within there: Name, Content Type, and Body.  It appears that I have to set the Content Type when doing this from Apex (unlike from doing it from the UI), if I try not to set it I get this error:

**FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Name, ContentType are required if Body is specified**

Now the issue is that when I try and set the Content Type, some values throw errors.  For example, if I try and set Content Type to "text/javascript", I get the error:

**bad value for restricted picklist field: text/javascript**

So my question is, are the valid picklist values for Content Type documented anywhere?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I was able to get the values using Describe methods, as discussed in this post:

[how to get a picklist all values in apex controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-get-a-picklist-all-values-in-apex-controller)

From this, I was able to figure out the list, which I will paste here if anyone else is interested.

application/html

application/java-archive

application/javascript

application/msword

application/octet-stream

application/octet-stream;type=unknown

application/opx

application/pdf

application/postscript

application/rtf

application/vnd.google-apps.document

application/vnd.google-apps.drawing

application/vnd.google-apps.form

application/vnd.google-apps.presentation

application/vnd.google-apps.script

application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

application/vnd.ms-excel

application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12

application/vnd.ms-infopath

application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12

application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12

application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation

application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet

application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template

application/vnd.visio

application/x-gzip

application/x-java-source

application/x-javascript

application/x-shockwave-flash

application/x-sql

application/x-zip-compressed

application/xhtml+xml

application/xml

application/zip

audio/mp4

audio/mpeg

audio/x-aac

audio/x-ms-wma

audio/x-ms-wmv

audio/x-wav

image/bmp

image/gif

image/jpeg

image/png

image/svg+xml

image/tiff

image/vnd.adobe.photoshop

image/vnd.dwg

image/x-photoshop

message/rfc822

text/css

text/csv

text/html

text/plain

text/rtf

text/snote

text/stypi

text/webviewhtml

text/x-c

text/x-c++

text/xml

video/mp4

video/mpeg

video/quicktime

video/x-m4v

video/x-ms-asf

video/x-msvideo