# how to get picklist values from stage

Tags: apex, picklist, visual

```
if(opp1.size()>0)
    {
        for(integer i=0;i<opp1.size();i++)
        { 

            //oppid=String.valueOf(opp1[i].get('Id'));
            stage=String.valueOf(opp1[i].get('StageName'));
            tmp1+='<th>'+stage+'</th>';
            counter++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the type of `opp1`? is it a list?

Comment: It looks fine. What is the issue??

Comment: What is your actual question - [ask]

Comment: Mr.Frodo its look fine but i want to show all stages values its show only one value that is already in oppotunity object and stage is the opportunity object field that contain 7 to 8 stage name so i can select all stage value stage type is picklist

Comment: This code will give you the value of stage field of the opportunity record you have fetched.If that you want to find out then this code is correct. or you need the values in the stage picklist??

Comment: yes i need the values in the stage picklist as a whole

Comment: i have posted an answer.Check if that satisfy your need.

Comment: yes sir it is helful for me

Comment: tell me the correct name of opportunity product

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the values of picklist you need to use `Schema.DescribeFieldResult`.

here is sample code to retrieve values of `StageName` picklist of `Opportunity` object.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry s:ple){

    System.debug('value: '+s.getLabel());
}
```

See [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-get-a-picklist-all-values-in-apex-controller) for more information.

Comment: this code show error

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe() opportunity.cls /basit/src/classes line 33 Force.com save problem

Comment: This code works fine.I have tested it.Can you update your code what are you doing?

Comment: public with sharing class opportunity{
public list<AggregateResult> opp{get;set;}
public opportunity()
 {
  opp=[select StageName from Opportunity group by StageName ];
public String getOpportunity_Plan()
    {
 string stage='';
 Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
   for(Schema.PicklistEntry s:ple)
   {
    stage=s.getLabel();
      
   } 
}
}

Comment: change name of your class from `Opportunity` to something else.It is conflicting.

Comment: tnx Mr.Frodo finaly i have got the picklist values of stagename thank you so much to help me

Comment: @abdulbasit Is this answer helpful??

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
stage=String.valueOf(opp1[i].get('StageName'));
```

by this :

```
stage=String.valueOf(opp1[i].StageName);
```

Regards,

Ajay

Comment: Both are correct. There is no need to replace.

Comment: Yes, of course Mr.Frodo you are right. Both are working.