# How to restrict the standard picklist values in Rest web service

Tags: apex, rest-api, picklist, rest, apexrest

below is my json where i am inserting the case record.

Status is standard field and the values are (New,Working,closed).

but if send the values other than the above values in json ,still its creating the records,but i wanted to throw an error.
in custom field if i choose restricted picklist option its trwoing an exception,but not for standard picklist values.
Please suggest

```
{
       "status" : "N",
       "origin" : "AIMS",
       "Custom_picklist":"Not allowed"
}

globalDesesr(string picklst){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =case.picklst.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    set <String> allOpts = new set <String> ();
    for(Schema.picklistEntry f:ple)    
    {    
        allOpts.add(f.getValue());        
    }

    return allOpts;   
}
```

Comment: What is restricted field option ?

Comment: how to check it for standard fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a validation rule on your status field. This validation will make sure if you enter any other value except the above three value it will not allow to save record.

```
NOT(ISPICKVAL(status , 'New')) && NOT(ISPICKVAL(status , 'Working')) && NOT(ISPICKVAL(status , 'Closed'))
```

Comment: is there any way in apex class only i can fix it?

Comment: @tarun. Check the status value in apex and if didn't match then just throw error.

Comment: I guess in apex its not good solution,because there may be possibility that new value can be added,In that case we need to change the code and add it in validation.Is there any way where we can restrict values like restricted options for custom picklist

Comment: You can use describe to get the status value dynamically and then compare with json inputs.

Comment: any sample code?thanks in advance

Comment: @tarun will help [Dynamic picklist value](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html)

Comment: Thanks tushar. I have written one method added above and it is working fine,only concern is when i am calling method by passing field name its throwing error-->Variable does not exist: case.picklst.Please suggest

Comment: @tarun you need `case.status` instead of `case.picklst`. If you want a utility you can try [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-to-get-a-picklist-all-values-in-apex-controller)

Comment: yes tushar. I am passing status string in method while calling like. 
     globalDesesr('status');     but still its throwing error

Comment: @tarun Share the updated code as of now it hard to debug without code.

Comment: no i just referred the above link and its working now.thanks for help

Comment: @tarun then you can close this question.